# Reference to object?

Tags: java, object, reference

I have an ArrayList of objects.
I "retrieve" one of those objects with something like:

```
MyObjectClass myObject = myArrayList.get(34);
```

If I subsequently make modifications to myObject, such as:

```
myObject.someMember = 97;
```

is it just doing it to a local COPY of the object or the actual object within the array list? That is, is the myObject variable a copy or is it a REFERENCE to the object within the array list?

Comment: I have added a [tag:Java] tag and answered for Java, but now I see C# also has an `ArrayList` class. Please change the tags if necessary, and always include a language tag in every question.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a name referring to an object always has reference semantics. Container `get` functions idiomatically return the same reference that the container holds.

If a function wants to return a local copy, or you want a local copy, this is done using `new`.

```
MyObjectClass myObject = new MyObjectClass( myArrayList.get(34) );
```

Comment: @Quirliom Without that, you simply can't have a copy.

Answer (score 1):

> is it just doing it to a local COPY of the object or the actual object
>   within the array   list? That is, is the myObject variable a copy or
>   is it a REFERENCE to the object within the  array list?

Yes it will make changes in the object state which is in ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Both myObject, and the item in the arraylist, are references to the object which is stored elsewhere.

The ArrayList does not hold the object, only a reference to the object (just like your reference to the object). Objects are never stored inside other objects in Java, although sometimes it is convenient to think of them that way.

Comment: Thank you, one and all for the responses. They clearly answered my question for me.